# Selected attribute not working with [(ngModel)] on select tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

In trying to put an `[(ngModel)]` on a select tag, the selected option no longer appears on loading the page. Before I put this on the select tag itself, the default option `State` was showing up just fine when I first loaded the page. Here is the code I have currently.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="inputState" name="inputState" [(ngModel)]="newJob.state" required>
          <option value="" invalid selected>State</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
          <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
          <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
          <option value="FL">Florida</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="ME">Maine</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
          <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MT">Montana</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
          <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="UT">Utah</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WA">Washington</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
```

TS:

```
export class NewJobListingComponent implements OnInit {
  isDeleted: boolean = false;
  currentTag: string = '';
  maxTags: boolean = false;


  newJob: JobListing = {
    jobTitle: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    department: '',
    type: '',
    tags: []
  };
}
```

As I said, before I put `[(ngModel)]` on `<select ...>`, the dropdown box was correctly displaying `State` when the page first rendered, and now it is not. I even tried initializing newJob.state to 'State', and that did not work either.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by " initializing newJob.state to 'State',  " the value  should have been `""` though since you have specified the value here `<option value="" invalid selected>State</option>`

Comment: also a stack blitz on above code seems to work fine , cant reproduce the error . perhaps you could share a stackblitz  of your code with us

Comment: and if you are trying to prevent user from clicking the default value then you should go for `<option value="" disabled selected>State</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following method by setting the default option style to `display: none`, It works for me. It acts as a placeholder when the user see the dropdown by default they ll see the `State`, when they open it, there'll be no `State` displayed. That's the hack. It acts like a placeholder.

```
<option value="" style="display: none">State</option>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Anyways what's the hack in this? can you explain bit more

Answer (score 0):

I change this

```
  newJob: JobListing = {
    jobTitle: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    department: '',
    type: '',
    tags: []
  };
```

to below code and work correctly

```
  newJob: any = {
    jobTitle: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    department: "",
    type: "",
    tags: []
  };
```